# The chromatic polynomial of the hyper cube graph $Q_4$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I need to research cube graphs for problems in evolutionary biology. To that end I have generated a few 100,000 graphs on the 4-cube. However, I want to double check that my list is correct. To that end it would be handy to have the [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial). By evaluating the polynomial at $x=-1$ one finds the number of [Directed Acyclic Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) on the 4-cube, according to a result by Stanley.

Does anyone know the chromatic polynomial of the hyper cube graph $Q_4$?

Comment: Posted also on MO: [Chromatic polynomial for hyper cube](https://mathoverflow.net/q/272701). I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice about cross-posting. And there are several other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting] on meta.

Comment: Dear Martin Sleziak, my question was put on hold. I have no clue why. I added context, but that did not help from my understanding. My best guess is that my question sorts under "research" rather than a student question. For that reason I asked the same question in mathoverflow. I greatly appreciate the answer I got, by the way.

Comment: If you think that the question is worth reopening, you can try to make your case in the [reopen request thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19042).

Answer (score 0):

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=chromatic%20polynomial%20hypercube%20graph) returns

$$x(x - 1)  (x^{14} - 31 x^{13} + 465 x^{12} - 4471 x^{11} + 30793 x^{10} - 160807 x^9 + 657229 x^8 - 2137667 x^7 + 5564285 x^6 - 11536667 x^5 + 18740317 x^4 - 23081607 x^3 + 20308039 x^2 - 11372201 x + 3040575)$$

probably using the usual deletion-contraction method.